# Generate a CSV file from a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, csv, propel

I can tell by looking at this code that I've gone about this in the wrong way.  Provided the string is correctly formatted (each index of`CSVData[][]`, would the following generate a CSV file?

There must be a more elegant way of taking my queries and building a CSV.  Looking at this code kinda makes me sick in the stomach.

```
class ShippingCSVGenerator
{
    public function generateShippingCSV($invoiceArray)
    {    
        $invoiceArray = $this->filterInvoices($invoiceArray);
        if(empty($invoiceArray))
        {
            // no parcels to fetch
            return;
        }
        $dispatchDataRes = \DispatchDataQuery::create()
            ->where('DispatchData.printed = ?', $invoiceArray)
            ->find();

        $index = 0;
        $CSVData = [];
        foreach($dispatchDataRes as $orders)
        {
            $parcelsRes = \ItemsInDispatchQuery::create()
                ->where('ItemsInDispatch.orderNumber = ?', $orders->orderNumber)
                ->find();

            $parcelIndex = 0;
            foreach($parclesRes as $parcel)
            {
                $CSVData[$index][$parcelIndex] = 
                    $orders->orderNumber() . ',' .
                    $orders->date() . ',' .
                    $orders->toName() . ',' .
                    $orders->destinationBuilding() . ',' .
                    $orders->destinationStreet() . ',' .
                    $orders->suburb() . ',' .
                    $orders->unused_7() . ',' .
                    $orders->postcode() . ',' .
                    $orders->state() . ',' .
                    $orders->country() . ',' .
                    $orders->email() . ',' .
                    $orders->phone() . ',' .
                    $orders->itemName() . ',' .
                    $orders->itemPrice() . ',' .
                    $orders->instructions() . ',' .
                    $parcel->weight() . ',' .
                    $orders->shippingMethod() . ',' .
                    $parcelIndex . ',' .
                    $orders->SKU() . ',' .
                    $orders->quantity() . ',' .
                    $orders->unused_21() . ',' .
                    $orders->unused_22() . ',' .
                    $orders->unused_23() . ',' .
                    $orders->unused_24() . ',' .
                    $parcel->height() . ',' .
                    $parcel->width() . ',' .
                    $parcel->length() . ',' .
                    $orders->courier() . ',' .
                    $orders->unused_29() . ',' .
                    $orders->unused_30();
                $parcelIndex++;
            }
            $index++;
        }

        header("Content-Type: text/csv");
        header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=shipping.csv');
        $fp = fopen("php://output", "w");
        fputcsv ($fp, $header, "\t");
        foreach($CSVData as $order)
        {
            foreach($csvOrder as $csvParcel)
            {
                fputcsv($fp, $csvParcel, "\n");
            }
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }

    private function filterInvoices($invoiceArray)
    {
        if(empty($invoiceArray))
        {
            // no parcels to fetch
            return;
        }
        $filteredInvoices = [];
        $dispatchDataRes = \DispatchDataQuery::create()
            ->where('DispatchData.printed = ?', $invoiceArray)
            ->find();
        if($dispatchDataRes->isEmpty())
        {
            // no parcels to fetch
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach($dispatchDataRes as $invoicesToFetch)
            {
                $filteredInvoices = $invoicesToFetch->getInvoiceNumber();
            }
        }
        return $filteredInvoices;
    }
}
```

Comment: How come you're fetching all attributes through function calls? why not do e.g. `$orders->orderNumber`? With a structure like that, you could just do `foreach ($orders as $key => $value) { ... }` and loop through all attributes. Otherwise you could do something like `foreach ($my_keys as $key) {$output_string .= $orders->$key . ',';}`.

Comment: Typo in csv writing foreach. Secong foreach should be `foreach($order as $csvParcel)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encapsulate the csv line generation in another function.

```
function GenerateCSVlineFromArray($array){
    $line = "";
    foreach ($array as $value){
        $line .= $value .",";
    }
    //cut last comma
    $line = substr($line, 0, strlen($line) -1);
    return $line;
}
```

Assuming you have already the right order of values.